# How to get the MAX & MIN using a CROSS APPLY in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a large query and part of it is this:

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                 employment.HireDate AS EarliestHireDate,
                 employment.TerminationDate
             FROM   
                 IntranetMIG.dbo.Employment employment
             WHERE  
                 employment.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId
                 AND (employment.TerminationDate IS NULL
                      OR employment.TerminationDate > @InputPeriodStart)
ORDER BY 
    employment.HireDate ASC) eh
```

This query is "cross applying" on the EARLIEST hire date.

I use this date elsewhere in my query. The thing is, I also need the LATEST hire date. I can't really do a `MAX()` because that'll break the `CROSS APPLY`.

How do I go about also selecting the LATEST hire date while at the same time, CROSS APPLYING to the EARLIEST hire date?

Comment: Lazy solution:  add another `CROSS APPLY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to add another `CROSS APPLY`:

```
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                                      employment.HireDate AS LatestHireDate,
                                      employment.TerminationDate
                               FROM   IntranetMIG.dbo.Employment employment
                               WHERE  employment.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId
                                      AND (
                                           employment.TerminationDate IS NULL
                                           OR employment.TerminationDate > 
                                           @InputPeriodStart
                                          )
                               ORDER BY employment.HireDate Desc) lhd
```

Comment: I guess that works. The reason why I didn't want to do this is because this cross apply takes awhile to run and I didnt want to have 2 of them. I can accept your answer in 4 mins.

Answer (score 1):

How about modifying your `cross apply` to do aggregation:

```
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(e.HireDate) AS EarliestHireDate,
                    MAX(e.HireDate) as LatestHireDate
                    MAX(e.TerminationDate) as FirstTerminationDate
             FROM  IntranetMIG.dbo.Employment e
             WHERE e.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId AND
                   (e.TerminationDate IS NULL OR e.TerminationDate > @InputPeriodStart)
            )
```

This probably shouldn't have a big performance impact, because the `cross apply` subquery was already doing an `order by`.